# How to create SQL trigger

Tags: sql, triggers

I have the following table: product(id, price, is_deleted)

I want to create a trigger that, when someone deletes a row from the PRODUCT table, instead of deleting it, changes the value of the column 'is_deleted' in that row to '1'.
The row that is to be deleted during the execution of a DELETE task must be temporary in a table called 'deleted'. It must also be the only row that is in the table 'deleted' on that moment.

This is what I thought:

```
CREATE TRIGGER is_deleted                                                                       
ON product
FOR INSERT      
AS         
BEGIN               
    UPDATE Product, is_deleted  = 1                    
    WHERE is_deleted = NULL
END
```

Is this a good way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You said "when someone deletes..., instead of deleting..." It looks like you're not actually deleting, but simply updating a column in the table. If that's the case, you don't need a trigger. And I didn't understand anything about that other table 'deleted.'

Comment: I'm guessing you meant "temporarily inserted" in a table. But why would you create a table that can only hold one row? Why not just delete the products in the product table that have the column "is_deleted" set to 1?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Not sure what you mean by the 'deleted' table. In SQL Server there are two special tables called Inserted and Deleted that are used by triggers and can be accessed in trigger code.  See: [Inserted and Deleted tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)